# PLL Output Option missing in Windows 10 after Update

Tags: windows, serial-port, usbserial, registrykey

I´m currently using a robot with a 4.5 Mbaud serial connection via com port. To archieve that speed I configured the pll in the comport settings. But after some windows Update the option PLL OuPut is not available anymore.

I tried reinstalling the comport drivers which does not work. 
Im still trying to find out what registry entries are connected to the settings mentioned above, so I can check if the option is gone or just not displayed.

Has anyone an idea how to find the com port registry entries mentioned here? The serial port entries documented by microsoft do not contain any settings in this whay and the program I found to scan for registry changes only works with PID´s.

EDIT:

I searched my registry with appropriate tools and hav not found any registry entries regarding the pll. So I think this is a Windows related Problem.

Actual Progress:
Windows provides property display classes, which allow modifying the properties in the device manager. Windows also provides an interface for driver developers to write additional property classes, which is propably the case with the chip I use. Since the driver has not changed since 2012 my guess would be, that windows has change his class structure someway and this results in some propertie not being displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final workaround is (for my case, hope it works for others as well) : close all driverrelevant programms and properties and disconneted the hardware that uses the driver. Open C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\ in Explorer. Copy .sys to C:\Windows\System32\drivers and override the existing file. Do the same with .EXE but copy it to C:\Windows\System32. Now connect the hardware again you should be able to use the pll again. –